# Boost: std_interoperability.hpp error: ‘std_category’ does not name a type

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

While I was trying to compile some C++ project on a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 installation, CMake complained that it couldn't find Boost at some point.

So I've installed it using

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

Now when I'm trying to compile the project, the compilation of some transitive dependency fails with the error message

```
/usr/include/boost/system/detail/std_interoperability.hpp:88:22:
error: ‘std_category’ does not name a type
   88 |         static const std_category generic_instance( &cat, 0x1F4D3 );
      |
```

The `gcc` version that I'm using is `9.3.0`, the `cmake --version` is `3.16.3`. The project itself should be more or less "fine", in the sense that it builds on at least one another machine; So, it must be something with the way I've installed the `boost` library locally.

I'd appreciate any hints about what could have gone wrong here and how to fix it.

I also see that it's not exactly an mcve (the non-reproducibility of the build, as well as the fact that something breaks in a transitive dependency are exactly my main problems right now), so I'd also greatly appreciate any hints on how to convert it into something reproducible, so that I can improve the question.

Comment: Are you sure this is **the first** error or warning message produced during the build? Definition of the class `std_category` comes at the beginning of the header [std_interoperability.hpp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/boost/system/detail/std_interoperability.hpp). Also, provide the **complete** error message, with all "transitive dependencies".

Comment: Also, see if you can make CMake preprocess your source and upload *that* - most often like `make test.cpp.i` (yes that's too big for [SO], but online pastebins should be okay)